# How to stream DJI Phantom video from android to "Wowza Server"?

Tags: streaming, h.264, wowza

I would like to stream my Phantom 4 video from android to streaming server like Wowza Server, that is possible?
Maybe someone give me some directions to do that?
I'm trying to write the code and have this function:

```
        // The callback for receiving the raw H264 video data for camera live view
    mReceivedVideoDataCallBack = new DJICamera.CameraReceivedVideoDataCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(byte[] videoBuffer, int size) {
            // Send the raw H264 video data to Wowza server here
        }
    };
```

With my research, we can use the libstreaming https://github.com/fyhertz/libstreaming for stream the phone Camera to Wowza server. But for my case that the data is H264 raw data, how can I stream it?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Wowza can't take in a raw H264 stream, it would need to be wrapped in some sort of transport like RTSP, RTMP or MPEG-TS.  The library you reference above will do just that, it supports taking h264 data and wrapping it in RTP for transport to a Wowza server.